# Branch Specific changes in Git

Tags: git, github

I am very new to git so forgive me for asking a silly question. I am working in a branch called `1796-CreateNewTrackingItem` that i created on git. I went to push some changes into develop. In doing so there were some conflicts, I thought that i made the correct changes but I didn't. That said 1796-... now isn't stable and doesn't build.

I started to play around with git and now i don't really know where I am at as far as which commit. But, I do know that I would like to be at the commit named code changes, and delete the one named 1796-Merge With Develop.

How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do this by doing the following steps.

```
git pull

git fetch

git merge
git reset HEAD~1 --hard
```